# Error code Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the number property of the Range class

Tags: excel, vba

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the
>   Range class

The code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cl As Range
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    For Each cl In Target

      If cl.Value <> "" Then
        check = MsgBox("Is this entry correct? This cell cannot be edited after entering a value.", vbYesNo, "Cell lock Notification")
        If check = vbYes Then
          cl.Locked = True
        Else
          cl.Value = ""
        End If        
     End If   
  Next cl

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 9 To 20
    If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" _
       And Cells(i, "C").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "D").Value <> "" _
       And Cells(i, "E").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "F").Value <> "" _
       And Cells(i, "G").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "H").Value <> "" _
       And Cells(i, "I").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "J").Value <> "" _
       And Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "L").Value <> "" _
       And Cells(i, "M").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "N").Value = "" Then

      Cells(i, "N").Value = Now
      Cells(i, "N").NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
    End If
  Next i
  Range("N9:N20").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you populate the cell *before* you change the content formatting?

Comment: What locale are you using?

Comment: What line of cde is causing the error?